# How can I trigger drag over or drag drop event in a form containing a listview when I drag items from a listView?

Tags: winforms, listview, drag-and-drop

I would like to trigger drag events when I drag selected items from a ListView in a C# Windows Forms application onto the enclosing form. The ListView AllowDrop Property is set to True to allow dragging within the ListView. If I set the form AllowDrop property to = true, the drag events are triggered when I drag items from outside the form, but not when I select ListView Items and drag them onto the enclosing form.

Comment: `AllowDrop` allows a Control to *accept* data coming from a DragDrop operation. Where do you want to drag the ListView iems to? Should the Form accept the Drop? To do what with the incoming data? Or another Control on the same Form should accept the data coming from the ListView? What is the `DataFormat`? What `DragDropEffects` have you set?

Comment: I don't want to do anything with the dragged item from the ListView, just perform an action on the  Drag Over event.

Effect set  as follows `private void PasteDragDrop_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
                e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy; }` The cursor changes to a no-entry sign when I drag onto PasteDragDrop form.

Comment: Changing code to `private void PasteDragDrop_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
  { e.Effect = DragDropEffects.All; }` fixed the problem! Thanks @Jimi